# What is the best Emacs workspaces plugin?

Tags: linux, emacs, aquamacs, workspace

By workspace, I mean - I need to save the state of my open buffers (possibly in a user specified workspace file) and quickly switch to another set of open buffers, e.g. to continue working on files related to another project.

Is there an Emacs plugin which allows this? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: A modern approach to this is eyebrowse: https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use a combination of [save-visited-files](https://github.com/nflath/save-visited-files) and [workgroups](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el).  In fact, workgroups will probably do most of what you want by itself.

My config:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; workgroups for windows

(setq wg-prefix-key (kbd "C-c z")
      wg-no-confirm t
      wg-file (concat emacs-persistence-directory "workgroups")
      wg-use-faces nil
      wg-switch-on-load nil)

(defun wg-load-default ()
  "Run `wg-load' on `wg-file'."
  (interactive)
  (wg-load wg-file))

(defun wg-save-default ()
  "Run `wg-save' on `wg-file'."
  (interactive)
  (when wg-list
    (with-temp-message ""
      (wg-save wg-file))))

(with-library 'workgroups
  (define-key wg-map (kbd "C-l") 'wg-load-default)
  (define-key wg-map (kbd "C-s") 'wg-save-default)
  (workgroups-mode 1)
  (add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'wg-save-default)
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'wg-save-default))
```

Comment: I wish switching to another workgroup would close all the buffers associated with the old workgroup and open new ones, instead of _just_ opening new ones.

Comment: `workgroups` does not have proper switching between sets of buffers, and loading/saving is a pain. I appreciate the answer, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: I agree that restoring (wg-restore-workgroup) and updating (wg-update-workgroup) can be a pain, because it requires discipline.  You could make some hooks to automate it, but it really should be something that's built in.  Loading and saving can be easily automated, e.g. with auto-save-hook as I did.  I stopped caring about open buffers long ago.  I clear some of them out every few days, and ido mode makes switching easy.  I have 91 buffers open right now.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've been actually searching all over to find a decent workspace and buffer organization mode/plugin, but with no luck. Workgroups are among the most decent among the things I saw, but they miss a few features.

Comment: is this comparable with the IDE(eclipse) PROJ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am using `workgroups` because `workgroups2` is having problem for me. My use case for `workgroup` is to save window configurations between sessions. As for buffers that are local to a project, I already have Projectile, so I don't wish `workgroups` to close all my buffers when switching to new one. That's just wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I've been using [`persp-mode'](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el):

> Perspectives for emacs, based on `perspective-el` by Nathan Weizenbaum.
>   But perspectives shared among frames + ability to save/restore from/to file.

Answer (score 2):

desktop.el will be helpful in your situation.

It can (copied from its introduction page) from the emacs packages buffer:

Save the Desktop, i.e.,
    - some global variables
    - the list of buffers with associated files.  For each buffer also
        - the major mode
        - the default directory
        - the point
        - the mark & mark-active
        - buffer-read-only
        - some local variables

Comment: I haven't tried with multiple desktop files, does it work? I thought it was more for saving state across Emacs restarts, which it does very well.

Comment: Yes it can: we can save a desktop file in a given directory (`desktop-save-in-directory`), and read it back (with an argument to `desktop-read`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux/Gnome3, you can try this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/361/emacs-manager/
This extension will allow you to work on different projects simultaneously by managing multiple emacs daemons, and save/restore state of buffers.

Answer (score 2):

HIROSE Yuuji's [revive.el](http://www.gentei.org/~yuuji/software/euc/revive.el) has worked nicely for me for quite some time. I use the standard configuration presented in the comments in revive.el. The documentation is well written and revive is very easy to use and configure. In particular, revive.el has better support than some for reviving configurations that are a bit more complex. It is particularly nice if you combine it with the HIROSE Yuuji's [windows.el](http://www.gentei.org/~yuuji/software/euc/windows.el). They are made to work together. windows.el makes it possible to recall window splits, etc. revive.el is built with an eye toward extensibility toward deeper mode integration for particular setups. But for my uses, I have found it to be quite nice out of the box, though I think I'll next tweak it to revive w3m windows which I currently don't have setup (Update: I do now: see bottom).

Here is my revive config. I include some helpful comments, first for windows.el and then revive.el inline:

```
(provide 'my-revive-config)

(require 'windows) ; use this with revive so that window splits are recallable
                   ; too

(win:startup-with-window) ; start with window 1


;;;[Key Bindings]
;;;
;;;   The default prefix key stroke for Windows is `C-c C-w'.  If it
;;; causes  you some  troubles, see  the  section  `Customizations'.
;;; Here are the default key bindings.
;;;
;;;     C-c C-w 1       Switch to window 1 (Q)
;;;     C-c C-w 2       Switch to window 2 (Q)
;;;        :
;;;     C-c C-w 9       Switch to window 9 (Q)
;;;     C-c C-w 0       Swap windows with the buffer 0 (Q)
;;;                 (Select unallocated frame(Emacs 19))
;;;     C-c C-w SPC     Switch to window previously shown (Q)
;;;     C-c C-w C-n     Switch to next window
;;;     C-c C-w C-p     Switch to previous window
;;;     C-c C-w !       Delete current window (Q)
;;;     C-c C-w C-w     Window operation menu
;;;     C-c C-w C-r     Resume menu
;;;     C-c C-w C-l     Local resume menu
;;;     C-c C-w C-s     Switch task
;;;     C-c C-w =       Show window list (Q)
;;;
;;;   The  key strokes  to  select  windows from  1    to 9 must  be
;;; frequently used, so the alternative key strokes `C-c [Num.]' are
;;; available  by default  (And  any  function  with (Q)mark can  be
;;; invoked without  C-w).  To disable these  quick key strokes, set
;;; the variable win:quick-selection to `nil' in your ~/.emacs.

(autoload 'save-current-configuration "revive" "Save status" t)
(autoload 'resume "revive" "Resume Emacs" t)
(autoload 'wipe "revive" "Wipe Emacs" t)

(define-key ctl-x-map "S" 'save-current-configuration)
(define-key ctl-x-map "F" 'resume)
(define-key ctl-x-map "K" 'wipe)

;;;
;;;[How to use]
;;;
;;;  Call `save-current-configuration' (`C-x S' if you define key as
;;; above) when you want to save current editing status and call
;;; `resume' to restore it. Numerical prefix arg to them specifies
;;; the buffer number in which the editing status will be saved.
;;; Here the buffer refers to a revive s-exp in ~/.revive.el of
;;; which there can be n
;;;
;;;     [Sample Operations]
;;;     C-u 2 C-x S     ;save status into the buffer #2
;;;     C-u 3 C-x F     ;load status from the buffer #3
```

There are variants of this that others like [revive-plus.el](https://github.com/martialboniou/revive-plus) and a [slightly modified clone on github](https://github.com/vedang/revive-mode), but I prefer the original.

Update Monday, January 12, 2015: Now I can restore w3m in revive (see revive.el docs for details and in particular look at examples in revive:major-mode-command-alist-default):

```
(setq revive:major-mode-command-alist-private
      '(("*w3m*"    . w3m)))
```

Notice you are telling revive the name of the w3m buffer. Even if you have multiple tabs, only the first one need be enumerated as above.

Here is the w3m variable I have set to restore all tabs from the previous session:

```
(setq w3m-session-load-last-sessions t)
```

Answer (score 0):

projectile mode may achieve what you what:

To switch buffers within a project: projectile-switch-to-buffer

To switch projects: projectile-switch-to-project

I have something like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") '(λ ()
                                (interactive)
                                (if (projectile-project-p) 
                                    (call-interactively 'projectile-switch-to-buffer)
                                (call-interactively 'ivy-switch-buffer))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x B") 'ivy-switch-buffer)
```