# Save Frames for future sessions

Tags: emacs, desktop, frames

Is there a way to save frames and their relative positions in emacs? 
I know that we could save windows using desktop.el ... this works fine 
but I also want to save the frames.

I have tried various options including frame-restore.el and desktopaid.el but they don't seem to work with various errors. Either they do not byte compile or give other errors.

Does some have nice clean way to save frames + desktop sessions in emacs?

Thanks!

Pawan

Comment: Maybe this can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263960/what-is-the-best-emacs-workspaces-plugin/11269086#11269086

Comment: `desktop.el` has a restore frames option -- does that not do the trick?  `(setq desktop-restore-frames t)`.  That option is available in Emacs Trunk, but I'm not certain when it was first implemented.  See also the related option of `desktop-restore-reuses-frames`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more about emacs internals try emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs 24.4 (which is not yet released) extends the Desktop feature of saving and restoring desktops (Emacs session state), to include frames and their positions, buffers (sometimes), etc.

You can obtain MS Windows executable builds of the development version of Emacs (what will become 24.4) [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin/).

If you have an Emacs build that supports this, consult the Emacs manual, node `Saving Emacs Sessions` for more information.

Comment: A bit surprising that such a useful feature has not been officially available till now within emacs :-) Probably the lisp gurus did not even bother because they could write such trivial things themselves :-)

Comment: No, I don't think so. Actually, it was quite a lot of work to implement -- we can thank Juanma Barranquero for doing it. I appreciate it especially for use with desktop bookmarks (in [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks)).